# Oracle Issue with Environment Variable 'ORACLE_UNQNAME'

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, command, environment-variables

I'm trying to install Oracle 11gR2 Entreprise Edition but during database creation, I got this Error :

```
Environment Variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined
```

And when I tried to lunch 'emctl.bat' From cmd  I got this one :

```
Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name.
```

And to slove this error, I have used this commande :

```
set ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl
```

To define my Enivronment variable (orcl is the database name) I got this error for the 'emctl' command:

```
EM Configuration issue. D:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/Chlebta-PC_orcl not found
```

So any Help For sloving this issue ?

Answer (score 9):

```
:\> emctl status dbconsole

Environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined.
Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name
```

Here is how to set oracle_unqname in Windows.  You use a similar "export command" in UNIX/Linux:

```
C:\>set ORACLE_HOSTNAME=localhost

C:\>set ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl

C:\>set ORACLE_SID=orcl

C:\>emctl status dbconsole

Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.1.0
Copyright (c) 1996, 2010 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: I apply this steps and then i restart my pc. and then this problem again occurred. Must i set this argument when i start my pc.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to set your environment variables is the graphical way :

```
control panel >  system > advanced system settings > Environment variables
```

now just click on new and inter the variable name : inter your variable name like 
**ORACLE_UNQNAME**
and int variable value : inter the value , such as [orcl](/questions/tagged/orcl)

now for the error of [em-configuration](/questions/tagged/em-configuration) : its seems like your host name "which is the computer name" is : [chlebta-pc](/questions/tagged/chlebta-pc) not [localhost](/questions/tagged/localhost) , check your [listener](/questions/tagged/listener) and make sure of the [host-name](/questions/tagged/host-name) in there and the host name of the         [variable-value](/questions/tagged/variable-value) .